# one class seems to block visibility of another?

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm using the Semplice theme on a self-hosted Wordpress-site and have a problem with displaying the sub-menu.

I have only quite poor css-knowledge, but after hours of try & error I have managed to make the disabled sub-menu re-appear again - at least it shows up partly. According to the visual overlay of my browser the sub-menu items are there, but only one of them gets displayed, the rest seem to be blocked by a different class!?
I've attached a screenshot to show you what I mean?!

[image: screenshot]

The submenu (vertical drowdown) sits under "units" and has six sub-nav items, but only one gets displayed, the others seem to be be hidden by the (hidden) responsive menu?!

I've tried the z-index but to no avail and now I'm really lost. I would greatly appreciate any help with this! Here's the site I'm working on:
http://s363619762.online.de/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the following style:

```
.navbar-inner {
    height: 131px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Remove the `overflow: hidden;` and it should work (This is just a solution for the current problem, don't know it it affects other places)

Comment: THX so much! Since I couldn't remove the "overflow: hidden" I added  "overflow: visible !important" to the class and from what I can see so far it doesn't affect anything else but makes my sub-nav show completely! THX again, you saved my day!